# Batch get DocumentReferences?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to improve a firestore get function, I have something like:

```
    return admin.firestore().collection("submissions").get().then(
        async (x) => {
            var toRet: any = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                try {
                    var hasMedia = x.docs[i].data()['mediaRef'];
                    if (hasMedia != null) {
                        var docData = (await x.docs[i].data()) as MediaSubmission;

                        let submission: MediaSubmission = new MediaSubmission();
                        submission.author = x.docs[i].data()['author'];
                        submission.description = x.docs[i].data()['description'];

                        var mediaRef = await admin.firestore().doc(docData.mediaRef).get();
                        submission.media = mediaRef.data() as MediaData;
                        toRet.push(submission);
                    }
                }
                catch (e) {
                    console.log("ERROR GETTIGN MEDIA: " + e);
                }
            }
            return res.status(200).send(toRet);
        });
```

The first get is fine but the performance is worst on the line:

```
var mediaRef = await admin.firestore().doc(docData.mediaRef).get();
```

I think this is because the call is not batched.

Would it be possible to do a batch get on an array of mediaRefs to improve performance?

Essentially I have a collection of documents which have foreign references stored by a string pointing to the path in a separate collection and getting those references has been proven to be slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this? I did some refactoring to use more await/async code, hopefully my comments are helpful.

The main idea is to use `Promise.all` and await all the mediaRefs retrieval

```
async function test(req, res) {
  // get all docs
  const { docs } = await admin
    .firestore()
    .collection('submissions')
    .get();

  // get data property only of docs with mediaRef
  const datas = await Promise.all(
    docs.map(doc => doc.data()).filter(data => data.mediaRef),
  );

  // get all media in one batch - this is the important change
  const mediaRefs = await Promise.all(
    datas.map(({ mediaRef }) =>
      admin
        .firestore()
        .doc(mediaRef)
        .get(),
    ),
  );

  // create return object
  const toRet = datas.map((data: MediaSubmission, i) => {
    const submission = new MediaSubmission();
    submission.author = data.author;
    submission.description = data.description;

    submission.media = mediaRefs[i].data() as MediaData;

    return submission;
  });
  return res.status(200).send(toRet);
}
```

Comment: hey, that's definitely faster and I'm marking it as the answer. One thing which I think is a small mistake is where you create submission you don't return it so toRet becomes a large array of nulls.